# What determines the size of a Tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I\m trying to shrink the width of my Text widget to fit the contents.

if I use,

```
>>> tktext.config(width=250)
>>> tktext.winfo_width()
650
```

Why does this happen? What are all the factors that determine a widget's width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you are seeing the discrepancy is thus:

1. The [`width`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.config-method) option sets the width of the textbox in **character units***.
2. The [`.winfo_width`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_width-method) method returns the width in **pixels**.

These two do not necessarily have to be the same (and rarely are).

**Note: I couldn't find a good link for the* `Tkinter.Text` `width` *option, so I added one for the* `Tkinter.Entry` `width` *option, which has the same principle.*