# Cannot fit tkinter.Text in pack() (also in grid() ) layout for a small parent widget

Tags: tkinter, layout

tkinter.Text() returns too big *winfo_reqwidth()* and *winfo_reqheight()* values (566 and 342 pixels for me) which prevents it to fit into a small widget.

For a parent widget big enough it's OK

Overriding *winfo_reqwidth()* and *winfo_reqheight()* in a child class did not help. It returns the values substituted but the widget's look is still the same.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

edit = tk.Text(root)
print(edit.winfo_reqwidth(), edit.winfo_reqheight())
edit.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

label = tk.Label(root, bg="red")
label.pack(fill=tk.X)

tk.mainloop()
```

I have to expand the root window by height to see the red label.

Does a layout hint exist to fit *tkinter.Text* into a *smaller* widget like 300x200 ?

But this may be a kind of bug when character units used somewhere inside instead of pixels like in
[What determines the size of a Tkinter Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128844/what-determines-the-size-of-a-tkinter-text-widget)

Comment: Have you considered giving the text widget a smaller size than the default?

Comment: As the `Text` widget is configured to expand and fill the available space in `pack(...)`, you can simply set the `height` of the `Text` widget to 1 when creating it.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen. I tried to impact on layout calls only in a hope they do the rest. The minimal height is in lines for the Text, not in pixels.

Comment: If you don't want to set (for some reasons) `height=` for `tk.Text`, you can use `grid()` layout and: `self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1);   self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`. I applied this solution finally.